# Enable JIT for QML in Raspberry

Tags: c++, qt, qml, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to create a QML and C++ application to work in a Raspberry. I'm adding some graphical effects like http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-zoomblur.html. The problem is, when I star the application, it appears a the message and the video is not shown:

```
libEGL warning: DRI3: failed to query the version
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
JIT is disabled for QML. Property bindings and animations will be very slow. Visit https://wiki.qt.io/V4 to learn about possible solutions for your platform.
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 1 (BadRequest), sequence: 405, resource id: 204, major code: 154 (Unknown), minor code: 1
```

how can i enable JIT for QML in Raspbian? Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you visit the proposed page?

Comment: Yes, in my case, it says: "understand why JIT is disabled for your platform". I've searched for that, and I have not found nothing

Comment: I am having this issue also.  My (incomplete) research indicates that ARMv6 cannot have both thumb and vfp enabled, which in turn disables JIT (I am unable to get thumb and non-vfp to work).  This contradicts the guides which indicate JIT enabled during cross compilation, but that's what I've found so far.

Comment: RPi3 has arm7 so that should not be in the way. Possibly it was not properly implemented yet?

Comment: Hi Have you find any solution for this?